# Spring Data GemFire DiskStore

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I need to persist the data in a `Region` to disk using Spring Data GemFire.

Using the config below (*Locator* and *Server* are started using *Gfsh*):

```
@EnablePdx
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableDiskStore(name = "disk_store")
@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp = true)
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackages = "xxx.entity")
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages = "xxx.repository")
public class GeodeClientConfiguration {

}
```

The config is below:

```
spring.data.gemfire.disk.store.name=disk_store
spring.data.gemfire.disk.store.directory.location=C:\\apache-geode-1.9.0\\diskstore
```

The above config creates a `DiskStore` (once the code to store the data is run). **The issue is that once the server is stopped, the disk store gets deleted.**

Looked at the documentation and examples by John Blum to no avail.

Also tried to create the `DiskStore` using *Gfsh* but end up with multiple `DiskStores` and no data in the disk store created in *Gfsh*.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with your Java configuration above, your arrangement is still a bit unclear/ambiguous to me. However, let's start with what we know.

First, it is clear from your Java configuration above that you are creating a `ClientCache`, *Spring* application to connect to and send/receive data to/from a standalone GemFire cluster.

You also state that you are starting the *Locator* and *Server(s)* using *Gfsh*.  All fine so far.

However, you have...

1) Annotated your client application class with `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions` (which is fine) without specifying an alternate data policy using the `clientRegionShortcut` attribute.  By default, the `clientRegionShortcut` is set to `PROXY` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableEntityDefinedRegions.html#clientRegionShortcut--)), which [means](http://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientRegionShortcut.html#PROXY) your client application keeps NO local state.

2) Then, you define a `DiskStore` (i.e. "disk_store") on the client with the `@EnableDiskStore` annotation, which is probably not what you want given there is currently NO local state kept on the client Regions.

> NOTE: `@EnableClusterConfiguration` does not push configuration meta-data for `DiskStores` up to the server from the client.  Currently, it only pushes `Region` and `Index` configuration meta-data up to the servers, as defined on the client.

Otherwise, the rest of the Spring (for GemFire) configuration (using Annotations) seems just fine.

> NOTE: Also keep in mind that the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation is careful not to stomp on existing Regions on the server-side.  If the same Regions by name already exist, then the server will not apply the definition sent by the client when declaring the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation (i.e. the annotation will not "nuke-and-pave").  That is by design, primarily to protect against data loss.
>
> NOTE: I also recommend that you use the type-safe alternative to the `basePackages` attribute, in both the `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions` and `@EnableGemfireRepositories` annotations, the `basePackageClasses` attribute.  It can refer to 1 or more Classes, but that class type is only used to determine the package from which to begin the scan.  For example, you can set the `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions`, `basePackageClasses` to `example.app.customers.model.Customer.class` and `example.app.products.model.Product.class` as in `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = { Customer.class, Product.class })` and SDG will use the package declaration of these classes to begin the Scan for Entity classes (sub-packages included).  You do not need to list all (or multiple) classes from the package; 1 per (top-level) package from where you want to scan will suffice.  It is good to limit the scan.

So, in your case, you probably want to do the following:

On the client:

```
@EnablePdx
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp = true)
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = EntityType.class)
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = RepositoryType.class)
public class GeodeClientConfiguration {

}
```

And then, on the server, to "persist" data, you want to create "PERSISTENT" Regions.  You can accomplish this 1 of 2 ways:

1) First, you can configure the client, using the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation, to tell the server when creating the matching Region (by name), as defined by the client, to create a "PERSISTENT" Region.  By default, the client-side `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation tells the server to create a non-persistent `PARTITION` Region (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableClusterConfiguration.html#serverRegionShortcut--)).  So you would change the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation in your client configuration to:

```
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp = true, serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.PARTITION_PERSISTENT)
...
class GeodeClientConfiguration { ... }
```

You may use any of the non-LOCAL, "PERSISTENT", `RegionShortcut`, Region (data policy) types (see [here](http://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionShortcut.html))... primarily [PARTITION_PERSISTENT* and REPLICATE_PERSISTENT*].

Then, when the client pushes the Region configuration meta-data to the server, the server will create a Region with the same name and designated (data policy) type (as defined by the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation's `serverRegionShortcut` attribute).

Again, keep in mind, that if the Region already exists, it will not re-create the Region.  If you want to have the client create the Region on (each application) restart, you need to destroy the Region using *Gfsh*.

2) Alternatively, you can use *Gfsh* to create the Region, using:

```
gfsh> create region --name=Example --type=PARTITION_PERSISTENT
```

Finally, when it comes to the `DiskStore`, since you have NO local state Region, and even if you did, you probably want the data "persisted" server-side instead, then if you do nothing and just declare the server-side Region(s) with a "PERSISTENT" data policy using 1 of the 2 methods above, then GemFire, by default, writes to the "DEFAULT" `DiskStore`.

If you want to associate a "specific" `DiskStore` (by name) with the Region (e.g. "Example"), then you must, first, create the `DiskStore` using *Gfsh*:

```
gfsh> create disk-store --name=disk_store ...
```

See [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_bkn_zty_ck).

And then, create the Region with *Gfsh*:

```
gfsh> create region --name=Example --type=PARTITION_PERSISTENT --disk-store=disk_store ...
```

See [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863).

The `DiskStore` is used both to "persist" data as well as overflow data to disk if you have Eviction configured to "OVERFLOW_TO_DISK" (see [here](http://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/EvictionAction.html#OVERFLOW_TO_DISK)).

From #2 (creating a Region) onward (with the `DiskStore` creation), is all server-side.

Anyway, I hope all of this makes sense and helps.

If you have additional questions or problems, feel free to follow up in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: Got it work perfectly. Turns out that I did not need to even specify a diskstore and the data is persisting to disk. Thanks a mil John Blum