# Problem creating region and persist region to disk Geode Gemfire Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gemfire, geode

I watched video from Springone Platform and John Blum as speaker and interested try myself in Geode/Gemfire setup but with setup as described in [Spring Data for Apache Geode Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#introduction)

So i make spring boot geode client, locator and cache server using Eclipse, and i have problems when :

1. Start spring locator, start cache server, and start client with restcontroller so I can post my POJO TitleContent and get my list of TitleContent. Client give me exception Caused by: `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:7070/gemfire/v1/regions": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Complete log :

```
2019-10-29 09:54:12.461 ERROR 58556 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:7070/gemfire/v1/regions": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at network.powerhouse.commercehost.CommerceHostGeodeApplication.main(CommerceHostGeodeApplication.java:51) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:7070/gemfire/v1/regions": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:751) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:644) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.admin.remote.RestHttpGemfireAdminTemplate.createRegion(RestHttpGemfireAdminTemplate.java:267) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.schema.definitions.RegionDefinition.create(RegionDefinition.java:125) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClusterConfigurationConfiguration$ClusterSchemaObjectInitializer.lambda$null$0(ClusterConfigurationConfiguration.java:403) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClusterConfigurationConfiguration$ClusterSchemaObjectInitializer.lambda$start$1(ClusterConfigurationConfiguration.java:402) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClusterConfigurationConfiguration$ClusterSchemaObjectInitializer.start(ClusterConfigurationConfiguration.java:402) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:657) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1075) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:742) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

2. I remark @EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp=true) and start Client again and now able to run. Now I give it a try with a POJO post to my restcontroller and get this exception :

   2019-10-29 09:43:08.193 ERROR 57276 --- [io-15050-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: remote server on 192.168.100.8(SpringBasedCacheClientApplication:57276:loner):64494:51246215:SpringBasedCacheClientApplication: : While performing a remote put; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on 192.168.100.8(SpringBasedCacheClientApplication:57276:loner):64494:51246215:SpringBasedCacheClientApplication: : While performing a remote put] with root cause

   org.apache.geode.cache.RegionDestroyedException: Server connection from [identity(192.168.100.8(SpringBasedCacheClientApplication:57276:loner):64494:51246215:SpringBasedCacheClientApplication,connection=1; port=64498]: Region named /TitleContent was not found during put request
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.writeRegionDestroyedEx(BaseCommand.java:624) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.Put65.cmdExecute(Put65.java:185) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.execute(BaseCommand.java:183) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doNormalMessage(ServerConnection.java:851) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.OriginalServerConnection.doOneMessage(OriginalServerConnection.java:75) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:1227) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) ~[na:na]
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl.lambda$initializeServerConnectionThreadPool$3(AcceptorImpl.java:616) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.logging.LoggingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(LoggingThreadFactory.java:121) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
3. This time I un-remark //@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp=true) but I remove useHttp and just use @EnableClusterConfiguration, (I suspected error because of this). I stop Spring Client and start it again. Now it fails, and says :  org.apache.geode.cache.RegionExistsException: /TitleContent.

The complete log :

```
Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.execute.FunctionException: org.apache.geode.cache.RegionExistsException: /TitleContent
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at network.powerhouse.commercehost.CommerceHostGeodeApplication.main(CommerceHostGeodeApplication.java:51) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.geode.cache.execute.FunctionException: org.apache.geode.cache.RegionExistsException: /TitleContent
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.ExecuteFunction66.cmdExecute(ExecuteFunction66.java:262) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.ExecuteFunction70.cmdExecute(ExecuteFunction70.java:66) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.execute(BaseCommand.java:183) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doNormalMessage(ServerConnection.java:851) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.OriginalServerConnection.doOneMessage(OriginalServerConnection.java:75) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:1227) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl.lambda$initializeServerConnectionThreadPool$3(AcceptorImpl.java:616) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.logging.LoggingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(LoggingThreadFactory.java:121) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.geode.cache.RegionExistsException: /TitleContent
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.createVMRegion(GemFireCacheImpl.java:2983) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.basicCreateRegion(GemFireCacheImpl.java:2938) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.createRegion(GemFireCacheImpl.java:2925) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.cache.RegionFactory.create(RegionFactory.java:755) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.admin.functions.CreateRegionFunction.createRegion(CreateRegionFunction.java:51) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:279) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.function.PojoFunctionWrapper.invokeTargetMethod(PojoFunctionWrapper.java:176) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.function.PojoFunctionWrapper.execute(PojoFunctionWrapper.java:155) ~[spring-data-geode-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.ExecuteFunction66.executeFunctionLocally(ExecuteFunction66.java:320) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.ExecuteFunction66.cmdExecute(ExecuteFunction66.java:250) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

4. This time I remark again //@EnableClusterConfiguration and start Spring Client again. This time it runs and I give a try again with the same POJO. It success !

Complete log :

```
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-29 10:04:04.477  INFO 59413 --- [io-15050-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-29 10:04:04.483  INFO 59413 --- [io-15050-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 6 ms
2019-10-29 10:04:04.598  INFO 59413 --- [io-15050-exec-1] o.a.geode.pdx.internal.TypeRegistry      : Caching PdxType[dsid=0, typenum=12150516
        name=network.powerhouse.commercehost.model.TitleContent
        fields=[
        id:Object:identity:0:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=-1
        code:String:1:1:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=1
        title:String:2:2:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=2
        content:String:3:3:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=3]]
```

5. I try to get list of TitleContent with GET rest endpoint at the controller with success.
6. Now I shut down all of them and restart them all. And i try to get the list as in point 5 and give me exception as in the complete log :

   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: remote server on 192.168.100.8(SpringBasedCacheClientApplication:59853:loner):49745:69bf7c15:SpringBasedCacheClientApplication: While performing a remote query; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on 192.168.100.8(SpringBasedCacheClientApplication:59853:loner):49745:69bf7c15:SpringBasedCacheClientApplication: While performing a remote query] with root cause

   org.apache.geode.cache.query.RegionNotFoundException: Region not found: /TitleContent
       at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.checkQueryOnPR(DefaultQuery.java:464) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:226) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommandQuery.processQueryUsingParams(BaseCommandQuery.java:120) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.Query651.cmdExecute(Query651.java:135) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.execute(BaseCommand.java:183) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doNormalMessage(ServerConnection.java:851) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.OriginalServerConnection.doOneMessage(OriginalServerConnection.java:75) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:1227) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) ~[na:na]
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl.lambda$initializeServerConnectionThreadPool$3(AcceptorImpl.java:616) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at org.apache.geode.internal.logging.LoggingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(LoggingThreadFactory.java:121) ~[geode-core-1.9.1.jar:na]
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

The Region looks like not persist to disk.

Questions :

At point 3 as exception was thrown, but definitely TitleContent region was created. But why exception is thrown?

Can somebody pinpoint what I missed, why @EnableClusterConfiguration behave strangely in my case and why Region is not persisted to disk (according to ref. manual, it should be persisted to disk by DEFAULT DiskStore at 7.12.7 ref. manual). I am sorry for such very long questions. I just couldn't make it shorter.

Thank you if somebody may be able to help, I really appreciate it.

The complete source code list:

SERVER :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@CacheServerApplication(locators="localhost[10334]", name="GeodeServerApplication" )
@EnableCacheServer(name="neptunus", autoStartup=true, hostnameForClients = "localhost", port = 48484)
//@EnableCachingDefinedRegions
//@EnableGemfireCaching
@EnablePdx
@EnableManager
@EnableHttpService
public class GeodeServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GeodeServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

LOCATOR :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@LocatorApplication(port = 10334)
public class GeodeLocatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GeodeLocatorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

CLIENT :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ClientCacheApplication(logLevel = "debug", locators = {@Locator(host = "localhost", port = 10334)})
@EnablePool(name="neptunusPool", servers=@Server(host="localhost", port=48484))
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses= {network.powerhouse.commercehost.repository.TitleContentRepository.class})
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses= {
        network.powerhouse.commercehost.model.TitleContent.class
})
@ReplicateRegion
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions
@EnableGemfireCaching
@EnableIndexing
//@EnableClusterConfiguration
@EnablePdx
public class CommerceHostGeodeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CommerceHostGeodeApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

CLIENT CONTROLLER :

```
@RestController
public class TitleContentController {

    @Autowired
    TitleContentService service;

    @PostMapping("/titlecontent")
    TitleContent postTitleContent(@RequestBody TitleContent titleContent) {

        return service.save(titleContent);
    }

    @GetMapping("titlecontent")
    List<TitleContent> getTitleContentByCode(@RequestParam("code") String code){

        return service.findByCode(code);

    }
}
```

CLIENT REPOSITORY :

```
@Region("TitleContent")
public interface TitleContentRepository extends CrudRepository<TitleContent, Long> {

    @Trace
    List<TitleContent> findByCode(String code);

}
```

CLIENT SERVICE :

```
public interface TitleContentServiceInterface {

    public TitleContent save(TitleContent titleContent);
    public void delete(TitleContent titleContent);
    public TitleContent findById(Long id);
    List<TitleContent> findByCode(String code);

}

@Service
public class TitleContentService implements TitleContentServiceInterface{

    @Autowired
    TitleContentRepository repo;


    @Override
    public TitleContent save(TitleContent titleContent) {

        return repo.save(titleContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(TitleContent titleContent) {
        repo.delete(titleContent);

    }

    @Override
    public TitleContent findById(Long id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<TitleContent> findByCode(String code) {
        return repo.findByCode(code);
    }

}
```

POJO :

```
@Region("TitleContent")
public class TitleContent {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Indexed
    private String code;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    public TitleContent(Long id, String code, String title, String content) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }
    public TitleContent() {
        super();
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TitleContent [id=" + id + ", code=" + code + ", title=" + title + ", content=" + content + "]";
    }



}
```

DEPENDENCIES:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

SPRING BOOT VERSION:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way around this, after reading answer from John Blum several time from [SpringData Gemfire DiskStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479867/spring-data-gemfire-diskstore).

Definitely  I couldn't use @EnableClusterConfiguration in my case (still wondering why). According to John, we are able to create Region using gfsh. From this I get an idea to do the same at Spring Boot CacheServer. So, how if I define my POJO at CacheServer and let annotation @EnableEntityDefinedRegions do the job to create the region at CacheServer side. Again I borrow

> serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.PARTITION_PERSISTENT

from John but I put it at

> @EnableEntityDefinedRegions

Beside that I also need to persist my PDX type (Spring and/or Geode Gemfire do not like me if I am not persisting Pdx type at CacheServer side). So, I am using the same method to persist from [SpringData Gemfire DiskStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479867/spring-data-gemfire-diskstore) but I implement it at CacheServer side with some additional entry at application.properties to tell spring to persist Pdx type as well.

In that way, I am able to successfully create and persisting Region at CacheServer side and also persisting Pdx as well.

Here is the complete code and application.properties I made with borrowing the idea from [SpringData Gemfire DiskStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479867/spring-data-gemfire-diskstore).

I appreciate if anybody able to tell me whether this work around is a good way to do or is there any other way or any better idea (still wondering though why @EnableClusterConfiguration doesn't like me while anybody else has no problem with it :=(, so if there is anybody who is able to tell me where is(are) my mistake(s) I really appreciate it ).

CLIENT :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ClientCacheApplication(logLevel = "debug", locators = {@Locator(host = "localhost", port = 10334)})
@EnablePool(name="neptunusPool", servers=@Server(host="localhost", port=41414))
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses= {TitleContentRepository.class})
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses= {TitleContent.class
})
//@ReplicateRegion
//@EnableClusterDefinedRegions
//@EnableCachingDefinedRegions
//@EnableGemfireCaching
@EnableIndexing
//@EnableClusterConfiguration
@EnablePdx

public class CommerceHostGeodeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CommerceHostGeodeApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

At client side the same POJO, Repository and RestController and nothing in application.properties except for server.port definition.

CACHESERVER :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@CacheServerApplication(locators="localhost[10334]", name="GeodeServerApplication" )
@EnableCacheServer(name="neptunus", autoStartup=true, hostnameForClients = "localhost", port = 41414)
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions
@EnableGemfireCaching
@EnablePdx
@EnableManager
@EnableHttpService
@EnableDiskStore(name = "disk_store")
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses= {TitleContent.class
}, serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.PARTITION_PERSISTENT)
public class GeodeServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GeodeServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

CACHESERVER application.properties :

```
server.port=15010
spring.data.gemfire.disk.store.name=disk_store
spring.data.gemfire.disk.store.directory.location=/Users/ars/geode/data
spring.data.gemfire.pdx.disk-store-name=disk_store
spring.data.gemfire.pdx.persistent=true
spring.data.gemfire.management.use-http=true
```

Upon CacheServer start, region is created and is able to persist / save to disk.