# started geode spring boot and save to remote region but failed to start bean gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

With a simple client app, make an object and object repository, connect to a Geode cluster, then run a @Bean ApplicationRunner to put some data to a remote region.

```
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "Web", locators = @Locator, logLevel = "debug", subscriptionEnabled = true)
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions
@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp = true)
@EnablePdx
public class MyCache {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCache.class);

@Bean
ApplicationRunner StartedUp(MyRepository myRepo){       
    log.info("In StartedUp");

    return args -> {            
    String guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8).toUpperCase();
    MyObject msg = new MyObject(guid, "Started");

    myRepo.save(msg);

    log.info("Out StartedUp");
    };
}
```

The "save" put fails with

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:7070/gemfire/v1/regions": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: This Exception really depends on how you started the GemFire or Geode servers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[Problem creating region and persist region to disk Geode Gemfire Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601177/problem-creating-region-and-persist-region-to-disk-geode-gemfire-spring-boot) helped. The problem is the `@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp = true)`

This annotation makes the remote cluster appear to be a localhost. If I remove it altogether then the put works.

If remove just the `useHttp = true` there is another error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on #.#.#.#(Web:9408:loner)### The function is not registered for function id CreateRegionFunction
```

Comment: Right, without `useHttp=true`, SDG, and specifically, the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation expects the servers in the cluster to have been configured and bootstrapped with SDG (or SBDG) using the Annotation-based configuration model.

Comment: If you are using Gfsh to configure/bootstrap your cluster of servers (recommended in most cases), then you must configure `useHttp=true`.  By using Gfsh, the Management REST API in the Locator should be available (which is only the case with a full distribution of GemFire/Geode).  If you adjusted the host/port of the embedded HTTP service/server (i.e. Jetty) in the GemFire/Geode Locator on startup, then you can specify the `host` and/or `port` attributes on the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the SDG `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation (details available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-cluster)) enables configuration metadata defined and declared on the client (i.e. Spring [Boot] Data, GemFire/Geode application) to be pushed from the client-side to the cluster (of GemFire/Geode servers).

I say "enable" because it depends on the client-side configuration metadata (i.e. Spring bean definitions you have explicitly or implicitly defined/declared).  Explicit configuration is configuration you defined with a bean definition (in XML, or JavaConfig with `@Bean`, etc).  Implicit configuration is *auto-configuration* or using SDG annotations like `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions` or `@EnableCachingDefinedRegions`, etc.

By default, the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation assumes the cluster of GemFire or Geode servers were configured and bootstrapped with *Spring*, and specifically using the SDG [Annotation configuration model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config).  When the GemFire or Geode servers are configured and bootstrapped with *Spring*, then SDG goes on to register some provided, canned GemFire Functions that the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation calls (by default and...) as a fallback.

> NOTE: See the [appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-cluster-configuration-bootstrapping) in the SBDG reference documentation on configuring and bootstrapping a GemFire or Geode server, or even a cluster of servers, with *Spring*.  This certainly simplifies local development and debugging as opposed to using *Gfsh*.  You can do all sorts of interesting combinations: Gfsh Locator with Spring servers, Spring [embedded|standalone] Locator with both Gfsh and Spring servers, etc.

Most of the time, users are using Spring on the client and Gfsh to (partially) configure and bootstrap their cluster (of servers).  When this is the case, then Spring is generally not on the servers' classpath and the "provided, canned" Functions I referred to above are not present and automatically registered.  In which case, you must rely on GemFire/Geodes internal, Management REST API (something I know a thing or 2 about, ;-) to send the configuration metadata from the client to the server/cluster.  This is why the `useHttp` attribute on the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` annotation must be set to `true`.

This is why you saw the Exception...

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; 

nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on #.#.#.#(Web:9408:loner)### 
    The function is not registered for function id CreateRegionFunction
```

The `CreateRegionFunction` is the canned Function provided by SDG out of the box, but only when Spring is used to both configure and bootstrap the servers in the cluster.

This generally works well for CI/CD environments, and especially our own test infrastructure since we typically do not have a full installations of either Apache Geode or Pivotal GemFire available to test with in those environments.  For 1, those artifacts must be resolvable from and artifact repository like Maven Central.  The Apache Geode (and especially) Pivotal GemFire distributions are not.  The JARs are, but the full distro isn't.  Anyway...

Hopefully, all of this makes sense up to this point.

I do have a recommendation if I may.

Given your application class definition begins with...

```java
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "Web", locators = @Locator, 
    logLevel = "debug", subscriptionEnabled = true)
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions
@EnableClusterConfiguration(useHttp = true)
@EnablePdx
public class MyCache { ... }
```

I would highly recommend simply using ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** (and Pivotal GemFire), i.e. SBDG, in place of SDG directly.

Your application class could then be simplified to:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableClusterAware
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions
public class MyCache { ... }
```

You can then externalize some of the hard coded configuration settings using the Spring Boot `application.properties` file:

```
spring.application.name=Web
spring.data.gemfire.cache.log-level=debug
spring.data.gemfire.pool.subscription-enabled=true
```

> NOTE: `@EnableClusterAware` is a much more robust and capable extension of `@EnableClusterConfiguration`.  See additional details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-declarative-annotations-productivity).

Here are a few resources to get you going:

- [Project Overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#getting-started)
- [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/guides/getting-started.html) Sample Guide
- [Use Case Driven Guides/Samples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-samples)
- Useful resources in the [Appendix TOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#appendix).
- Detailed information on SBDG provided [Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto).
- Detailed information on [Declarative Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-declarative).
- Detailed information on [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-externalized).

In general, SBDG, which is based on SDG, SSDG and STDG, is the preferred/recommended starting point for all things *Spring* for Apache Geode and Pivotal GemFire (or now, Pivotal Cloud Cache).

Hope this helps.