# @EnableClusterAware annotation with remote GFSH started Geode server requires HTTP configuration

Tags: geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

We run a GFSH managed Geode cluster with several .Net clients, and now I am incorporating a new spring boot data Geode client for rSocket web endpoints with webflux. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459852) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409732) I want to properly autoconfigure the SDG client application with `@EnableClusterAware` and `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions`. When I do so like this:

```
package app;
.. (imports) ..
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"admin", "region", "rsocket", "webflux"}) // scans packages for @ components
@EnableLogging(logLevel="info", logFile="geode.log")
public class Web {
```

and

```
package admin;
.. (imports) ..
@EnableClusterAware
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut=ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
@UseMemberName("WebServer")
public class ClientCache {
```

with `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=Web
spring.data.gemfire.pool.locators=1.2.3.4[10334]
spring.data.gemfire.pool.subscription-enabled=true
```

then the client cache application starts up and it appears to get the DEFAULT pool and connect to the remote GFSH server

```
INFO  [main] org.apach.geode.cache.clien.inter.PoolImpl 349 start: Pool DEFAULT started with multiuser-authentication=false
INFO  [Cache Client Updater Thread  on 1.2.3.4(UAT:12900)<v1>:41001(version:UNKNOWN[ordinal=105]) port 40404] org.apach.geode.inter.cache.tier.socke.CacheClientUpdater 1581 processMessages: Cache Client Updater Thread  on 1.2.3.4(UAT:12900)<v1>:41001(version:UNKNOWN[ordinal=105]) port 40404 (1.2.3.4:40404) : ready to process messages.
```

but I am not seeing the server regions being setup per `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions`. This means that when I navigate to `http://localhost:8082/doWork` the `@RestController` endpoint handler fails with:

```
Error creating bean with name 'MyRestController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.geode.cache.Region<java.lang.String, region.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

Which is because the server regions are not being initialised. If I add `@EnableGemFireHttpSession` then I get an error `[gemfirePool] is not resolvable as a Pool in the application context` and so I define my own pool like `@EnableGemFireHttpSession(poolName="webPool")` with an additional `@Bean`:

```
@Bean("webPool")
PoolFactoryBean sessionPool() {
    PoolFactoryBean pool = new PoolFactoryBean();
    ConnectionEndpoint ce = new ConnectionEndpoint("1.2.3.4", 10334);       
    pool.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
    pool.addLocators(ce);
    return pool;
}
```

and now the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` gets to the server and instantiates all the regions I need for me. Great... but then the show fails with:

```
WARN  [main] org.sprin.conte.suppo.AbstractApplicationContext 558 refresh: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:7070/gemfire/v1/regions": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The only solution I can find so far is to remove `@EnableClusterAware` and use the annotations:

```
package admin;
.. (imports) ..
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut=ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
@UseMemberName("WebServer")
@EnableGemFireHttpSession(poolName="webPool")
public class ClientCache {
```

which sets up all the regions for me, but then I am running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226331)

In `build.gradle` I'm using

```
implementation 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter:1.2.4.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-geode:2.2.2.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion around `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions`. `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` uses the regions that are already declared on your server to configure your client regions, not the other way around. What it sounds like you want is `@EnableClusterConfiguration`, which will push regions defined by your client to the server. However, you don't need to declare `@EnableClusterConfiguration` explicitly, because `@ClusterAware` is meta-annotated with `@EnableClusterConfiguration`.

As for why your regions are not being created, I'm guessing that your region definitions are not being found. I notice your `ClientCache` class is not annotated with `@Component` even though you are component scanning its package; is the class in which you defined your region annotate with `@Component`? If not, try adding it.

Comment: Thanks, shall try adding @Component. Though it’s about getting regions defined on the server to the client, which are used across tens of services, they’re centrally configured.... for now.....